# hyperlinks for tcolorbox

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox

I'm trying to get hyperlinks working for tcolorboxes. But when I click on the link in the pdf documents, I'm getting an error on console `Failed to lookup label` error. I tried both phantom and label with tcolorbox. None of them worked. The minimum working code is here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Lipsum, phantom={\phantomsection{\label{lipsum}}}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\clearpage
\newpage

Lipsum is \hyperlink{lipsum}{here}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With TeXLive 2013 the MWE you provided works.

Comment: I was using TeXLive 2013 and it was not working for me :( \hypertarget worked for me though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\phantomsection\hypertarget{lipsum}`, since a `\label` does not have a direct relationship with `\hyperlink`. The latter expects a `\hypertarget`.